# Getting the proper last row that has data when using getlastrow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all, I am a scripting noob.

I am trying to write a function that calls a variable called `lastrow`. When I use the `getlastRow`, it returns the row at the bottom of sheet that has no data in it. I am using array formulas, that use "" ..I believe that is causing the `lastrow` to be the bottom of the sheet.

Is there a way to get the proper last row of actual data ?

I have been modifying a script by Andrew Roberts. Here is some of the code

```js
var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
  copyId = copyFile.getId(),
  copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
  copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection(),
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
  lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow(),
  numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
  activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(),
  activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
  headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
  columnIndex = 0,
  recipient = activeSheet.getRange(lastRow, 24).getValues();

for (;columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {

copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%', 
                     lastRow[columnIndex])
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to add an minimum example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

getLastRow() returns the last row that has content, even if the content of a cell in the last row is an empty string (`""`) which is not the same as a blank cell, so your guess is right that arrays with `""` could be causing that the last row is not what you expect.

Regarding the proper way, if you are able to avoid to add empty strings then fix that. If you are not able to do so, you should define your own assumptions regarding which could be the last row or to compare each row from the bottom to the top until you find a non empty row.

Comment: Ruben,
Thank you for the response. Regarding the bottom paragraph. I use a form that sends to a spreadsheet. From there I have another tab that has all of the formulas for calculating. My responses and output from those formulas are a mixture of strings and numbers. I cannot think of a way to not pass "" values. If I do not use those, I will get unintended values.

Comment: @JordonPeeple Create a [mcve]  including a typical formula and add them to your question.